# Errors with writing score in python

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I am currently making a simple turtle game and when I try to write a score, it does not show even though it is above the background layer (turtle.write is at the bottom and the code has been shortend).

```html
import turtle
score = 0
score = 0
px = 0
py = 260

s = turtle.Screen()
s.setup(width=600, height=500)
s.bgcolor("black")

pen = turtle.Turtle()
pen.color("white")
pen.penup()
pen.goto(0, 260)

cr = turtle.Turtle()
cr.penup()
cr.shape("square")
cr.color("white")
cr.shapesize(stretch_len=4, stretch_wid=0.01)
cr.goto(x,y)

cr2 = turtle.Turtle()
cr2.penup()
cr2.shape("square")
cr2.color("white")
cr2.shapesize(stretch_len=0.01, stretch_wid=4)
cr2.goto(x,y)
while True:
    s.update()

    if cr.xcor() != cr2.ycor():
        cr.setx(cr2.xcor())
    if cr.ycor() != cr2.xcor():
        cr.sety(cr2.ycor())
    pen.write("hello!")
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code example is unrunnable.  Regardless, let's consider these three lines:

```
s.setup(width=600, height=500)
pen.goto(0, 260)
pen.write("hello!")
```

The first line sets the range of visible Y coordinates to -250 to +250.  The second line moves the pen to a Y coordinate of 260, off the top of the screen.  The third line writes text that's off the top of the screen.  Change the Y coordinate in the second line from 250 to 240, putting that turtle back onto the screen, and you'll see the output of the `write()`.